# Array of Pointers from inside structure to other structures of the same type

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic, struct

I'm having trouble with pointers.  My program has many pointers and most of them are working correctly, but I'm trying to add an array of pointers inside an array of structs that points to a different member in the same array of structs.  This is supposed to be a little like a linked list but also have the benefit of being arrays.  The arrays need to be allocated dynamically because the data is an array of structures with elements inside that are arrays of structures with elements inside them which are arrays of fundamental types with quantities of each unknown until runtime.  I've tried making static allocated arrays to hold all the data but it ends up being many megabytes.

I've created a stripped down test program below that only has the portions that I am having difficulty with.

In the line `groups[0].sub_group[0] = groups[1];` I'm trying to assign the pointer to the address of `groups[1]` into the `groups[0].sub_group`.  This does compile but it gives a runtime error 'EXE_BAD_ACCESS'.  I thought the line should be `groups[0].sub_group[0] = &groups[1];` but this doesn't even compile.

Ultimately I want to run this from inside a function, so I also need to be able to make this assignment with a pointer to groups, something like `(*p_groups)[0].sub_group[0] = groups[1];` but this doesn't work either.

If I may also ask a related question: What is the difference between:

`(*p_groups)[0].sub_group[0] = groups[1];` and

`p_groups[0]->sub_group[0] = groups[1];` ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char * text;
    int data_type_count;    // count of elements in data_type_list
    char * bacnet_name;     // string of name
} pup_item_t;

typedef struct pup_group_t pup_group_t;
struct pup_group_t {
    char * title;            // Null Title indicates end of list
    pup_item_t * items;      // array of items
    int item_count;          //count of items
    pup_group_t * sub_group; // array of pointers to associated sub groups
    int sub_group_count;     // count of sub groups
};

typedef pup_group_t * pup_group_array_t;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    pup_group_array_t groups = (pup_group_t *)malloc(sizeof(pup_group_t) * 2);
    groups[0].items = (pup_item_t *)malloc(sizeof(pup_item_t)*2);
    groups[1].items = (pup_item_t *)malloc(sizeof(pup_item_t)*2);
    pup_group_array_t * p_groups;
    p_groups = &groups;

    groups[0].items[0].text = strdup("Group 0 Text 0");
    groups[0].items[1].text = strdup("Group 0 Text 1");
    groups[1].items[0].text = strdup("Group 1 Text 0");
    groups[1].items[1].text = strdup("Group 1 Text 1");

    groups[0].sub_group[0]      = groups[1]; // <-- EXE_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address = 0x0)
    (*p_groups)[0].sub_group[0] = groups[1]; // <-- EXE_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address = 0x0)

    printf("%s \n",groups[0].items[0].text);            // prints "Group 0 Text 0"
    printf("%s \n",groups[1].items[1].text);            // prints "Group 1 Text 1"
    printf("%s \n",groups[0].sub_group->items[1].text); // <-- EXE_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address = 0x8)
                                                        // should print "Group 1 Text 1"
    return 0;
}
```

**Update 6/30/2014**

You were right in my example code I forgot to malloc the **sub_group**.  However in my live code I did not forget to do this.  My live code is several thousand lines and much too big to post here.  I have edited the example code to be closer to my live code.  The sample code now compiles and works correctly (as far as I can tell).  But my live code does not execute.

Here is the updated sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct {
    char * text;
    int data_type_count;    // count of elements in data_type_list
    char * bacnet_name;     // string of name
} pup_item_t;


typedef struct pup_group_t pup_group_t;
struct pup_group_t {
    char * title;            // Null Title indicates end of list
    pup_item_t * items;      // array of items
    int item_count;          //count of items
    pup_group_t * sub_group; // array of pointers to associated sub groups
    int sub_group_count;     // count of sub groups
};

typedef pup_group_t * pup_group_array_t;

void allocate_groups(pup_group_array_t * p_groups) {
    *p_groups = (pup_group_t *)malloc(sizeof(pup_group_t) * 2);
    p_groups[0]->items = (pup_item_t *)malloc(sizeof(pup_item_t) *2 );
    p_groups[1]->items = (pup_item_t *)malloc(sizeof(pup_item_t) *2 );
    p_groups[0]->sub_group = (pup_group_t *)malloc(sizeof(pup_group_t)* 2);
}

void assign_groups(pup_group_array_t * p_groups) {
    p_groups[0]->items[0].text = strdup("Group 0 Text 0");
    p_groups[0]->items[1].text = strdup("Group 0 Text 1");
    p_groups[1]->items[0].text = strdup("Group 1 Text 0");
    p_groups[1]->items[1].text = strdup("Group 1 Text 1");
    p_groups[0]->sub_group[0] = *p_groups[1];
}

void print_groups(pup_group_array_t * p_groups) {
    printf("%s \n",p_groups[0]->items[0].text);             // prints "Group 0 Text 0"
    printf("%s \n",p_groups[1]->items[1].text);             // prints "Group 1 Text 1"
    printf("%s \n",p_groups[0]->sub_group[0].items[1].text);// prints "Group 1 Text 1"
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    pup_group_array_t groups = NULL;

    allocate_groups(&groups);
    assign_groups(&groups);
    print_groups(&groups);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the portion of my live code that crashes when running:

```
int allocate_groups_array(char * filename, pup_group_array_t * p_groups, int * p_bacnet_count) {
    int i, size;
    int item[MAX_GROUPS_PER_FILE] = {0};
    int levels[MAX_GROUPS_PER_FILE] = {0};

    int count = scan_pup_file("ct9-103.pup", item, levels, p_bacnet_count);

    *p_groups = (pup_group_t *)malloc(sizeof(pup_group_t)*(count+1));
    for (i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
        size = sizeof(pup_item_t) * (item[i]);
        p_groups[i]->items = (pup_item_t *)malloc(size); // EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = 0x18)
        printf("group %d is level %d has %d items with size of %d \n",i,levels[i],item[i], size);
    }

    assign_sub_groups (p_groups, count, item, levels);

    return count;
}
```

The values of size and the other variables are correct.  But the malloc `p_groups[i]->items = (pup_item_t *)malloc(size);` returns EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  What am I doing wrong?

** Update 6/30/2014 pm **

Here is the working version that someone helped me with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct {
    char * text;
    int data_type_count;    // count of elements in data_type_list
    char * bacnet_name;     // string of name
} pup_item_t;


typedef struct pup_group_t pup_group_t;
struct pup_group_t {
    char * title;            // Null Title indicates end of list
    pup_item_t * items;      // array of items
    int item_count;          //count of items
    pup_group_t * sub_group; // array of pointers to associated sub groups
    int sub_group_count;     // count of sub groups
};

//typedef pup_group_t * pup_group_array_t;

pup_group_t * allocate_groups() {
    pup_group_t * p_groups = (pup_group_t *)calloc(sizeof(pup_group_t) , 201);
    p_groups[0].items = (pup_item_t *)malloc(sizeof(pup_item_t) *201 );
    p_groups[1].items = (pup_item_t *)malloc(sizeof(pup_item_t) *201 );
    p_groups[200].items = (pup_item_t *)malloc(sizeof(pup_item_t) *201 );
    p_groups[0].sub_group = (pup_group_t *)malloc(sizeof(pup_group_t *)* 201);
    return p_groups;
}

void assign_groups(pup_group_t * p_groups) {
    p_groups[0].items[0].text = "Group 0 Text 0";
    p_groups[200].items[0].text = "Group 200 Text 1";
    p_groups[1].items[200].text = "Group 1 Text 200";
    p_groups[1].items[200].text = "Group 1 Text 200";
    p_groups[200].items[200].text = "Group 200 Text 200";
    p_groups[0].sub_group[0] = p_groups[200];
}

void print_groups(pup_group_t * p_groups) {
    printf("%s \n",p_groups[0].items[0].text);                // prints "Group 0 Text 0"
    printf("%s \n",p_groups[200].items[0].text);              // prints "Group 200 Text 1"
    printf("%s \n",p_groups[0].sub_group[0].items[200].text); // prints "Group 200 Text 200"

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    pup_group_t * groups = allocate_groups();

    assign_groups(groups);
    print_groups(groups);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't allocated any storage for the `sub_group` member variable. You'll need to `malloc` that, too.

Edit for Updated code: For the real code, I fear that may be harder to diagnose.

See if you can access the `items` member at all, oh, wait a second. `p_groups` is a hidden pointer, so you've got a double-pointer. And it's a single pointer to an array. So shouldn't it be:

```
(*p_groups)[i].items = ...
```

? I think you might be trashing your memory, and it could be malloc itself which couldn't find its metadata. You can also lose the casts to malloc, which are not necessary in C.

---

> If I may also ask a related question: What is the difference between:

```
(*p_groups)[0].sub_group[0] = groups[1]; and

p_groups[0]->sub_group[0] = groups[1]; ?
```

Yes. I notice you already suspected something like this. The difference is the first line accesses a *pointer to array* and the second line accesses an *array of pointers*. They're both *double-indirections*, but they place the array in different positions.

It's easier to see if we rewrite the second expression to be in a similar parenthesized form,

```
(*p_groups[0]).sub_groups[0] = groups[1];
```

and the postfix operator applies first, so it's equivalent to this.

```
(*(p_groups[0])).sub_groups[0] = groups[1];
```

Small tests can be misleading because index 0 will work. `*E` == `*(E+0)` == `E[0]`. And other "small" indices may not be *too far* out of bounds to cause serious trouble. But little weird things will happen, which you've probably been experiencing. Changing a line fixes something even though the change shouldn't really change anything, stuff like that, that's what trashed memory does.

If you'll forgive a little ascii art,

```
[ -> ]
[ -> ]
[ -> ]
[ -> ]

-> [ ]
   [ ]
   [ ]
   [ ]
```